# Proving that (X,Y) is not bivariate normal

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=X$ if $|X|>c$ and $Y=-X$ if $|X|<c$, for any $c>0$.

I've already proved that $Y \sim N(0,1)$.

How do we prove that $(X,Y)$ is not a bivariate normal?

I've tried proving that $Cov(X,Y)=0$ and because they are not independent, then we reached our desired conclusion. However, I only get $Cov(X,Y)= 1-E(X^2\mathbb{1}_{|X|<c})$ which is $0$ only for some $c$... and doesn't prove for all values of $c>0$.

Then how can I prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Showing that $Cov(X,Y) = 0$ is not going to lead you anywhere, since if $Cov(X,Y) = 0$, would just indicate that their covariance is 0, and say nothing much about the existence of a joint distribution.

By the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definition) of a multivariate normal distribution, $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal if every linear combination of X and Y is Normal. So to show that $(X,Y)$ is not jointly normal, you need to find $a$ and $b$ such that
$$aX + bY \not \sim \text{Normally distributed} $$

So consider $X - Y$.

\begin{align*}
X - Y &= 
\begin{cases}
X - |X| & \text{when} |X| > c\\
X + |X| & \text{when} |X| < c
\end{cases}\\
& = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ when } |X| > \max\{0, c\}\\
0 & \text{ when } c <0 \text{ and } \min\{0,c\} < |X| < \max\{0, c\}\\
2X & \text{ when } c \geq 0 \text{ and }\min\{0,c\} < |X| < \max\{0, c\}\\
2X & \text {when } |X| < \min\{0, c\}
\end{cases}\\
\end{align*}

Then, trivially, irrespective of the value of $c$,  $P(X - Y = 0) > 0$, and thus $X - Y$ is not normally distributed. Thus, $X$ and $Y$ are not bivariate normal.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just a point, though. If Cov =0 and had they had joint normal distribution, then it would imply that they were independent. Since, they clearly are not, we would be able to say that they didn't have joint normal distr.

Comment: @Klenke2ed That is reasonable logic, but you only know they they are not independent by intuition, and not by definition. So it may not lead to a sound proof by contradiction. Anyway, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

**An interesting observation:**

> If $(X,Y)$ is a bivariate normal then the support takes every values of $\mathbb{R^2}$. Then $XY$ takes every value in Real line.

---

Now here $XY=X^2$ if $|X|>c$ and $XY=-X^2$ if $|X|<c$. Then $XY$ do not take any less than $-c^2$, which leads to $(X,Y)$ can not be a bivariate normal.